# MSBuild ItemGroup, excluding .svn directories and files within

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration

How can I construct a MSBuild ItemGroup to exclude .svn directories and all files within (recursively). I've got:

```
<ItemGroup> 
     <LibraryFiles Include="$(LibrariesReleaseDir)\**\*.*" Exclude=".svn" />
</ItemGroup>
```

At the moment, but this does not exclude anything!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Thanks for your help, managed to sort it as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <LibraryFiles Include="$(LibrariesReleaseDir)\**\*.*" 
                   Exclude="$(LibrariesReleaseDir)\**\.svn\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Turns out the pattern matching basically runs on files, so you have to exclude everything BELOW the `.svn` directories (`.svn\\**`) for MSBuild to exclude the `.svn` directory itself.

Comment: @Kieran Benton: thanks for the update, I'm going to submit a connect.microsoft.com request to clarify the MSDN documentation.

Comment: I notice that you also prefixed the Exclude value with "$(LibrariesReleaseDir)\\**\" (compared to the value in your OP).  Is that significant?

Answer (score 12):

So the issue is with chaining variables for some reason in msbuild.  The following works for me, notice that I have to only use relative paths based on the MSBuildProjectDirectory variable.

```
<CreateItem Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Client\Web\Foo.Web.UI\**\*.*"
            Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Client\Web\Foo.Web.UI\**\.svn\**">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="WebFiles" />
</CreateItem>
```

The following does not work:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <WebProjectDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Client\Web\Foo.Web.UI</WebProjectDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<CreateItem Include="$(WebProjectDir)\**\*.*"
            Exclude="$(WebProjectDir)\**\.svn\**">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="WebFiles" />
</CreateItem>
```

Very strange!  I just spent like 3 hrs on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an even better way to do it, truly recursively.  I can't seem to get your solution to go more than 1 level deep:

```
<LibraryFiles  
    Include="$(LibrariesReleaseDir)**\*.*"  
    Exclude="$(LibrariesReleaseDir)**\.svn\**\*.*"/>
```

Comment: Does this work on the .svn\entries file as well, given that there's no dot in the filename?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into some glitches using the Include/Exclude approach, so here's something that's worked for me instead:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyFiles Include=".\PathToYourStuff\**" />
    <MyFiles Remove=".\PathToYourStuff\**\.svn\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```